# How to add Style on document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, css

I have a loader image that is displaying in the left corner in my iFrame however, I am trying to display in center. Could you please advise how can add style in the following code:

```
var ShowLoader = function() {
    document.getElementById("mainIframe").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("documentIframe").src = "http://localhost:63902/images/loading.gif";
}
```

Comment: What is wrong in using `document.getElementById("mainIframe").style`?

Comment: Question and description and code didn't match

Comment: `.style.textAlign = "center"` maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below code to center align.

```
document.getElementById("documentIframe").style.textAlign = "center";
document.getElementById("documentIframe").style.margin = "0px auto";
```